# Bootstrap - How to center col in row with fixed pixels

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a container who must have max-width 960px. Inside the container is a row with max-width 928px, who has 2 cols inside. The left col has a max-width 576px and the right col has a max-width 352px. How can i center the 2 cols, so that they are exactly in the middle of the container ? What is the trick with bootstrap 4 ?

```
 <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-self-center" style="max-width: 960px;">
  <div class="container" style="max-width:960px;">

   <div class="row" style="max-width:928px;">


     <div class="col" style="max-width:576px;"> 
      ... data ...
     </div>

     <div class="col" style="max-width:352px;"> 
     ... data ...
     </div>

    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

I made 2 pictures to show what is the problem and what i wanna do in the end (fixed version ...). Thank you very much for each answer !!!
[Is now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIFw4.png)
[Must be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWmE7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't need a `min-width` or `min-height` for the containers and you need them centered vertically too, this should do the trick

```css
.yellowBg {
  background-color: yellow;
}
  
.tomatoBg {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-self-center" style="max-width: 960px; border: 2px solid black;">
  <div class="row" style="max-width:960px;">
    <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="max-width:928px;">
    
      <div class="col d-flex flex-row flex-wrap justify-content-start yellowBg" style="max-width:576px;"> 
        <p> stuff here </p>
        <p> stuff here </p>
        <p> stuff here </p>
        <p> stuff here </p>
        <p> stuff here </p>
        <p> stuff here </p>
        <p> stuff here </p>
        <p> stuff here </p>
        <p> stuff here </p>
        <p> stuff here </p>
        <p> stuff here </p>
        <p> stuff here </p>
        <p> stuff here </p>
        <p> stuff here </p>
      </div>
    
      <div class="col d-flex flex-row flex-wrap justify-content-start tomatoBg" style="max-width:352px;"> 
        <p> more stuff here </p>
        <p> more stuff here </p>
        <p> more stuff here </p>
        <p> more stuff here </p>
        <p> more stuff here </p>
        <p> more stuff here </p>
        <p> more stuff here </p>
        <p> more stuff here </p>
        <p> more stuff here </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```